# Online removal of images from Keras pipeline

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

I am using in Keras the *flow_from_directory* method to load images from specific categories, where folders in my train path correspond to the different classes. This works all fine.

I am now in the situation that I’d like to remove specific image files during analysis due to annotation errors. At the same time, to maintain the raw data I would not like to resort to removing the images from disk.

On the other hand, creating a new file structure without the removed images would undesirably add disk memory.

I was wondering if Keras offers a way to enter a simple list of image filenames that should be ignored during the training stage, such as `[example1.jpg, example9.jpg, example18.jpg]`. Is there anywhere during *ImageDataGenerator* or *flow_from_directory* a parameter where this can be done ?

Any advice would be welcome !

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing but i changed my strategy, i would think it would be helpful for you too; i tried out to make a dataframe for the images and the labels and then remove the rows for the images that don't wanna to flow into model and then instead of flow from directory, i used flow from dataframe

by this way, you could even remove images based on particular labels, size, created time, modified time, and etc.

Comment: thank you for your help. *flow_from_dataframe* assumes that all data are in a single directory, isn't it? My data are partitioned in different folders which corresponds to the different classes. It feels a bit unnatural to copy all these data to one folder and label them using a DataFrame. Is there a way to use *flow_from_dataframe* with different directories?

Comment: yes, you could do it based on two methods; define the directory parameter in flow from dataframe and set it to direcotry address, and then set filename column in dataframe something like this `subdir/filename.jpg` or by the second method set directory to None in flow from dataframe, and set filename column with complete address. so its possible to use it even for files in subdirs by these methods.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to this solution! I am using the second one, -- set directory to None and refer to the complete image path under *x_col* --. I am optimistic that this will be working soon :-)